# Python django, is possible to present the output of a view directly in a html template?

Tags: python, html, django

Let's suppose you have a django project, the response of one of its views is an image, if you want to insert that image inside an HTML document you do:

```
<img src="/path_to_my_view/">
```

Then, when the user open the Webpage that return that HTML document he will see the image. Nothing new at this point.

Now, what happens if the response of that "view" is not an image but a simple text, there is no HTML tag to embed a simple text, so, how would you do it?

The view code that return a simple text is:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def view(request):
    return HttpResponse('Simple line of text returned by my view')
```

So, what I would like to do in my html is something like this:

```
<p>The exit of the view was: <?HTML_TAG? src="/path_to_my_view/"></p>
```

Or something like this (using Django template language):

```
<p>The exit of the view was: {{ MyProjectApp.view }}</p>
```

But I have not found any one of those alternatives yet.

The current solution to the problem is by using the object HTML tag:

```
<object width="400" height="400" data="/path_to_my_view/"></object>
```

However I'm not happy with this solution, it seems like using a cannon to kill a bug, I think that I'm missing something.

Thank you for your support!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for an `<iframe>`, which is the way of embedding one HTML document inside the other:

```
<iframe src='/path_to_my_view/'>
```

However since these are both views on the same server, I don't know why you want to embed it via HTML. Why not simply call the view from your other view and pass the result as a context variable? Or, even better, factor out the code whose result you want into a common method, called by both views.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 choices here: either you use a TemplateView that you map directly to your url and in that template you add your html code.

The other solution is to interpret a string as a template and render it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my question:

View.py

```
def myview(request):
    content ='Hello I am an innocent string'
    response = HttpResponse(content, content_type='text/plain')
    return response
```

template.html

```
<object type="text/plain" data="/myapp/"></object>
```

Hope it helps someone else!

Bye!